# Memory test using all CPUs?

Tags: memory, cpu

I have been using MemTest86 4.3.7 to test my system memory but although it knows there are 8 CPI cores, it will only test 4 (I asked it to cycle through all and left it testing for 13 hours).  using UFEI mode and MemTest86 5.1, it will only test 1.  I think the BIOS is up-to-date but also, MemTest86 4.3 should handle as many as 64 CPUs.

I'm especially interested in this since my backup software is complaining about memory issue but when testing with 4 CPU cores, it doesn't find anything.

Read disk E: at position 188412067840 failed. Image file is corrupted. Decompression failed. Check system memory for errors

motherboard MSI Z68A-GD55 G3
CPI i7-26000  "4 cores / 8-way multitask processing"

Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: What complaint is your backup software making?

Comment: More details about the problem, please. I guess you have an Intel CPU with HT? So you have 4 physical cores, including the "virtual" HT cores, windows will show 8 "CPU"s. Maybe that's the reason for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your replies; please see extra information in the question.  @davidbaumann, you're correct--it _is_ 4 cores!  looks like that's the answer here; if you put it in as an answer, I can accept that answer.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have 4 physical cores, so only 4 cores will be tested.

Windows will show you 8 cores, as there are 4 physical cores, and 4 virtual [HyperThreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) cores.